# Easiest way to highlight/underline specific words (by location) in a file based on the output of an external program?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, autocmd

I have a program that I run on a file and the output of the program is a line number.
If I save this line number in a temporary file, can I get vim to automatically highlight or underline this word/line like a linter would?

What's the easiest way to do this without plugins?

I was thinking, if possible, to have a file watcher, but I'm not sure how I could link this up to neovim.

Comment: You could look at text properties to highlight. But if your goal is to jump to those locations, I would use the quickfix or location list

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, goal is not to jump to those locations, just highlight them like a linter would highlight an unused variable

Comment: I would suggest trying to integrate with something like ALE, then, but text properties are the best bet for building something solo

Comment: I figured out, I think, that all I need is a python scripts with `pynvim` that watches file changes and communicates with vim in response. Is there a proper way to make this filewatcher asynchronously? First search brings up the python package `watchdog`